# Execute an onChange trigger X seconds after change in a Google Sheet using appsscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a newbie to Google Apps script. I need some help. I want to run a code 10 seconds after a change has happened in a google sheet. How do I do that?
Please help. kindly know I want to use onChnage Trigger and not a time-based trigger.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For example, how about using [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)?

Comment: For anything less than on minute you would need to use `Utilities.sleep()` as suggested by Tanaike. Alternatively, you can set up a time-based trigger which will run at a specific time, with a minimum of one minute in the future

Comment: @tanaike & Rafa  Can you please elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Actually I need to run a code when the last change happens in my google sheet. My sheet undergoes a change of values in many cells, hence a simple on change trigger sends multiple emails and I need it to send just one. therefore I want the script to execute after the last change is done.

Comment: Not really enough information to go on here without spending a lot of time guessing your set up. Can you provide sanitised code?